# An Inner join in an Outer Join leading to peformance shortfalls, what is a different approach?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, dimensional-modeling

I have a view in one of my databases that is retrieving the previous and current case officers(think person) from a few tables and views. The issue is these records are only linked by the end date(saoh.Date_TO) being the same as another case officers start date (saoh.Date_FROM).

To create a join between these records I am currently doing an outer join with an inner join inside it. (This can be seen in the script below). The issue is the view has ~3 million records. This means to then query this view is taking an extremely long time (2-3 hours).

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to improve the fundamental design of the SQL below.

**Further Information**
**Environment:** MSSQL server 2008
**Other Info:** Snapshot_Period is a tool for reporting and not linked to the case officer dates.

```
   ALTER VIEW [dbo].[vw_Stage_Estate_Case_Officer_Source] AS
    SELECT  sp.SNAPSHOT_PERIOD_START_DATETIME,
            sp.SNAPSHOT_PERIOD_END_DATETIME,
            aes.APPLICATION_RID,
            aes.ESTATE_RID,
            aes.TRUSTEE_NUMBER,
            aes.TRUSTEE_TYPE,
            aes.TEAM_CODE,
            saoh.POSITION,
            saoh.DATE_FROM,
            saoh.DATE_TO,
            saoh.ERROR_CONDITION,
            saoch.USER_ID as PRIOR_CASE_OFFICER
    FROM    Stage_App_Estate_Statuses aes
            /*Standard snapshot period new join for MonthlyITS and yearlyTIS*/
            INNER JOIN  Stage_Snapshot_Period_New sp ON
                        change_date < sp.SNAPSHOT_PERIOD_END_DATETIME and
                        sp.SNAPSHOT_PERIOD_IS_FINALISED_INDICATOR = 'No'and 
                       (sp.SNAPSHOT_PERIOD_TYPE_NAME = 'MonthlyITS' or sp.SNAPSHOT_PERIOD_TYPE_NAME = 'YearlyITS')
            /*This should be inner joining to the staging table that links Case officers to team codes by region*/
            INNER JOIN  [DEV_STAGING].[dbo].[STAGE_STAF_ACTION_OFFICERS] saoh ON
                        aes.TEAM_CODE = saoh.POSITION AND LEFT(aes.ESTATE_RID,3) = LEFT(saoh.ACTION_OFFICER_RID,3)
            /*This should be inner joining to App_Estate_Statues again to get the previous UserID*/
            LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT staf.USER_ID,
                                staf.DATE_FROM, 
                                staf.DATE_TO,
                                a.TEAM_CODE,
                                a.ESTATE_RID
                        FROM [DEV_STAGING].[dbo].[STAGE_STAF_ACTION_OFFICERS] staf
                        INNER JOIN  Stage_App_Estate_Statuses a ON
                                    a.TEAM_CODE = staf.POSITION) saoch  ON
                         saoh.DATE_TO = saoch.DATE_FROM AND saoch.ESTATE_RID = aes.ESTATE_RID

    GO
```

**Table Definitions**
**Snapshot Period:** Irrelevant / Must stay as is. 
**Stage App Estate Statuses:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Stage_App_Estate_Statuses](
    [ESTATE_STATUS_RID] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [ESTATE_RID] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
    [CATEGORY] [decimal](1, 0) NULL,
    [CHANGE_DATE] [datetime2](0) NULL,
    [CHANGE_TYPE] [nvarchar](3) NULL,
    [STATUS] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
    [TEAM_CODE] [nvarchar](4) NULL,
    [TRUSTEE_NUMBER] [decimal](22, 0) NULL,
    [TRUSTEE_TYPE] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [APPLICATION_RID] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
    [DML_TYPE] [nvarchar](1) NOT NULL,
    [AUDIT_KEY] [int] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

**Stage_STAF_ACTION_OFFICERS**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Stage_STAF_ACTION_OFFICERS](
    [ACTION_OFFICER_RID] [nvarchar](15) NOT NULL,
    [POSITION] [nvarchar](13) NULL,
    [DATE_FROM] [date] NULL,
    [DATE_TO] [date] NULL,
    [USER_ID] [nvarchar](32) NULL,
    [ERROR_CONDITION] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [EXTRACTED_DATE] [date] NULL,
    [DML_TYPE] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
    [AUDIT_KEY] [int] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: Schema? Execution plan?

Comment: The `LEFT(aes.ESTATE_RID,3) = LEFT(saoh.ACTION_OFFICER_RID,3)` is problematic.

Comment: @MitchWheat Good pickup, Schema is DBO.That left statement is a limitation from the source tables that certain identifiers are reused (Horrible Source System). and the only change is the first 3 characters of both of those statements. The data quality is quite high though in that the comparison there is reliable for all rows of both tables.

Comment: @MichaelBetterton, please post table definitions.

Comment: Whey do you need the derived table?  I forget the syntax but I have seen it.

Comment: @wewesthemenace I've posted the table defintions, sadly I cannot post example data due to data sensitivity.

Comment: @Blam as I said in the question, I need to find the current and previous case officer for every estate. i.e 1 Row per estate per Case officer

Comment: So, that has nothing to do with the need for doing that with a derived table

Comment: Can you verify what is the performance bottleneck? Can you remove `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and `saoch.USER_ID` from `SELECT` to see if performance changes significantly? If it does, then we can look into making this part better.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov From building this query I can confirm that the Left outer join with an inner join inside it on itself causes the performance issue. I have almost reached a solution through using a with statement then performing an outer left join on that. The query is not correct data wise atm, but it has reduced query time from ~3minutes to ~15 seconds.

Comment: @MichaelBetterton, how big are `Stage_App_Estate_Statuses` and `Stage_STAF_ACTION_OFFICERS` ? what indexes do they have? Why in the first `INNER JOIN` you join them by `aes.TEAM_CODE = saoh.POSITION AND LEFT(aes.ESTATE_RID,3) = LEFT(saoh.ACTION_OFFICER_RID,3)`, but then you join by `a.TEAM_CODE = staf.POSITION` and `saoch.ESTATE_RID = aes.ESTATE_RID`. Second time you don't use `ACTION_OFFICER_RID`, which is strange. Would it be correct to join these two tables once and use results in two places later (using another view or CTE)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its hard not having anything to test against so just treat this as a starting point

```
SELECT
    sp.SNAPSHOT_PERIOD_START_DATETIME,
    sp.SNAPSHOT_PERIOD_END_DATETIME,
    aes.APPLICATION_RID,
    aes.ESTATE_RID,
    aes.TRUSTEE_NUMBER,
    aes.TRUSTEE_TYPE,
    aes.TEAM_CODE,
    saoh.POSITION,
    saoh.DATE_FROM,
    saoh.DATE_TO,
    saoh.ERROR_CONDITION,
    (select USER_ID
        from [DEV_STAGING].[dbo].[STAGE_STAF_ACTION_OFFICERS] sao
        where sao.DATE_FROM = saoh.DATE_TO
            and (select ESTATE_RID from Stage_App_Estate_Statuses where TEAM_CODE = sao.POSITION) = aes.ESTATE_RID
    )as PRIOR_CASE_OFFICER --Even if this approach doesnt help, keep the original join as outer because there might not be a prior_case_officer
FROM
    Stage_App_Estate_Statuses aes
    /This should be inner joining to the staging table that links Case officers to team codes by region/
    INNER JOIN [DEV_STAGING].[dbo].[STAGE_STAF_ACTION_OFFICERS] saoh 
        ON aes.TEAM_CODE = saoh.POSITION 
        AND LEFT(aes.ESTATE_RID,3) = LEFT(saoh.ACTION_OFFICER_RID,3)
            /Standard snapshot period new join for MonthlyITS and yearlyTIS/
    INNER JOIN (select

                    SNAPSHOT_PERIOD_START_DATETIME,
                    SNAPSHOT_PERIOD_END_DATETIME,

                from Stage_Snapshot_Period_New
                where 
                    SNAPSHOT_PERIOD_IS_FINALISED_INDICATOR = 'No'
                    and SNAPSHOT_PERIOD_TYPE_NAME in ('MonthlyITS','YearlyITS')
                ) sp
        ON change_date < sp.SNAPSHOT_PERIOD_END_DATETIME
```

Comment: Thank ou for your input, I understand it is incredibly hard to test against without a dataset but as I said before it is too sensitive to post. You are correct in your assumption that there is not always a prior case officer.  I was looking into using a with statement instead of the double join. Do you have any thoughts on that?

Comment: I meant no database - I cant even syntax check it... ive already noticed there are some stray commas and the comments have had their * removed. as for Common table expression (CTE) (I think that is what you mean re: "WITH", it would just be a matter of trying it. My script is really just a couple of other things you could try.

Comment: Given this is a performance thing we would have needed A LOT of data anyway... but for problems with a smaller dataset, you can still fudge the data, we don't need actual data just something that is representative.

Comment: @G B Ok, yes as I said there are quite a few million rows and as such it would be quite hard to tell performance wise on a small data set. But for future questions I'll remember this.  In regards to the With statement, I think I've almost got there with it. I'll post it up if I come to a result thats satisfying.

Comment: cool thx, can you also give mine a run and see what the performance is like and post it... Im just curious :-)

Comment: I've actually managed to solve the problem using your code as a base. The inner joins needed to be changed to left outer joins and I used  a where statement. For reference, your query was slightly quicker than the original, however mine is down to about 30 seconds. I'll pick your answer as correct as this is not a Q&A question type but ill post mine below for reference.

Comment: Also I removed the snapshot_period reference in my answer which actually means I had a larger result set. Meaning after including the snapshot_period reference my code was down to a very quick execution time.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you may be able to turn the "inner join in the outer join" into multiple left joins, though your where clause will then need to handle the situations that the inner join in the subquery was dealing with, for example:

```
... query same up to the left join ...
            /*This should be inner joining to App_Estate_Statues again to get the previous UserID*/
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[STAGE_STAF_ACTION_OFFICERS] saoch
               ON saoh.DATE_TO = saoch.DATE_FROM
                 AND saoch.POSITION = aes.TEAM_CODE
            LEFT OUTER JOIN Stage_App_Estate_Statuses a ON
                 a.TEAM_CODE = saoch.POSITION
                 AND a.ESTATE_RID = aes.ESTATE_RID
    WHERE (saoch.ACTION_OFFICER_RID IS NULL)
       OR (saoch.ACTION_OFFICER_RID IS NOT NULL AND a.ESTATE_STATUS_RID IS NOT NULL)
```

I simplified the tables to remove the irrelevant bits and added some dummy data; with the dummy data I used this query returns the same results as the original but a different query plan -- meaning you'll have to test it to determine if it performs better or not.

Here's [the SQLFiddle I used](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3971be/10/0).

Answer (score 0):

My final working code after inspiration from the answer above.

```
WITH curr AS
    (SELECT est.ESTATE_RID
        ,est.TEAM_CODE
        ,staff.POSITION
        ,ISNULL(staff.USER_ID, su.System_User_ID) as USERID
        ,est.CHANGE_DATE
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY est.ESTATE_RID DESC, est.CHANGE_DATE ASC) AS RowNum
        FROM Stage_App_Estate_Statuses est
            LEFT OUTER JOIN Stage_STAF_ACTION_OFFICERS staff ON
            est.TEAM_CODE = staff.POSITION and
            est.CHANGE_DATE BETWEEN staff.DATE_FROM AND staff.DATE_TO
            LEFT OUTER JOIN Stage_System_User_Mapping su on
            est.TEAM_CODE = su.System_User_ID
        WHERE CHANGE_TYPE LIKE '%T%'
    )
SELECT  curr.ESTATE_RID, 
        curr.TEAM_CODE,
        ISNULL(curr.USERID,curr.TEAM_CODE) AS Current_UserID,
        prev.USERID AS Previous_UserID,
        curr.CHANGE_DATE as Date_From,
        helper.CHANGE_DATE as Date_To
FROM curr
LEFT OUTER JOIN curr prev ON    curr.RowNum = (prev.RowNum + 1) and
                                curr.ESTATE_RID = prev.ESTATE_RID                           
LEFT OUTER JOIN curr helper ON curr.RowNum = (helper.RowNum - 1) and
                                curr.ESTATE_RID = helper.ESTATE_RID

ORDER BY ESTATE_RID ASC, curr.CHANGE_DATE ASC
```